# Where do I setup Windows 7 to not hibernate when laptop's lid is closed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, hibernate

Where do I setup Windows 7 to not hibernate when laptop's lid is closed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In power management.

> Control panel → Power options → Advanced settings

Answer (score 5):

Control Panel, Power Options, on the left - "choose what closing the lid does."