# Where can I stop windows 7 from hibernating on leaving the lid closed for a long time?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hibernate

As asked. This is different from [another similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/27199/where-do-i-setup-windows-7-to-not-hibernate-when-laptops-lid-is-closed) in that I already went to Control panel → Power options → Advanced settings and told windows to do nothing on lid close, both on and off battery.

When I close the lid, indeed nothing happens- for a while. After maybe more than half an hour (haven't measured), it hibernates. I do not know how to stop this as it's nowhere to be seen in power options.

Comment: have you got your answer?

Comment: No I haven't gotten a damn answer. All three answers say the same thing, all of them ignore the part where I say I ALREADY turned off hibernation on lid close and on idle time.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have change for lid close only... Check your `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings` for other power plan and make change as you required...

Answer (score 0):

On my Vista laptop you go to Control Panel ->Power Options ->Change when the computer sleeps.  Then press "Change advanced power settings", which gets you to a Properties-like window labeled "Power Options".  It has Advanced settings and VAIO Power Management tabs on my box.

On the Advanced settings tab find the "Sleep" item and open it, turn off the "hybrid sleep" and "hibernate after" settings.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your computer is hibernating is probably because it is set to do so after a certain time of inactivity. It has nothing to do with whether or not the lid is closed.

You have various options in the Power Settings. One controls what happens when you close the lid, you have successfully set it to "nothing". Another controls what happens when the computer has been left idle for a while, set that to never hibernate as well and you should see the expected behavior.

Comment: No, It isn't. It really, really isn't. Word of honor. If I leave the lid open it just sits there happily, at worst the screen dims (as it's supposed to given the settings). When I close the lid, the settings are ignored and it hibernates after a while.